# How to go from bottom of the page to the top of the page?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, nestedscrollview

I create an form with 15 editText inside NestedScrollView. Suppose second editText is empty. So after clicking **Submit** button, I want that page directly goes to the 2nd editText from **Submit** button to show error. But I don't know how to go from **Submit** button to second editText directly. Can you help me ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can use `scrollTo()` or `smoothScrollTo()` as mentioned here

1. To make it simpler, create a function as below:

   ```
   //Used to smooth scroll the scrollbar to focused view.
   //@param view : parameter view is any view you want to scroll to
   //view.bottom indicates that you want to scroll to the bottom of the view, 
   //you can change it to view.top
   private fun smoothScrollToThis(view: View) {
       scrollView.post { scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, view.bottom) }
       /* view.post{} here is a runnable function and uses a separate thread to perform
      the operation so the UI doesn't freeze.*/
   }
   ```

   This will scroll the `ScrollBar` to the view. Difference between `scrollTo` and `smoothScrollTo` is that `scrollTo` scrolls instantly skipping the in-between part and `smoothScrollTo` works like an actual scroll by a user showing all the widgets in between while scrolling. For a long layout of `ScrollView`, you should prefer `scrollTo` as it's fast.
2. Now, call the function from wherever you want as:

   ```
   smoothScrollToThis(yourEditText) //You can pass any view
   ```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach I generally use is this:

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // sets focus on the editText such that the ScrollView automatically scrolls to the EditText
                editText.requestFocus();        
                // displays the error message on the EditText
                editText.setError("error message" ); 
            }
        });
```